# How to type a fixed-length generator in typescript?

Tags: javascript, typescript, generator

I have a Vector2 class in typescript below.

```js
// Vector2.ts
class Vector2 {
  constructor (public x, public y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
  }

  //... A bunch of vector methods

  public* [Symbol.iterator]: Generator<number, void, unkown> {
    yield this.x;
    yield this.y;
  }
}

// main.js
const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

const a = new Vector2(0, 0);
const b = new Vector2(10, 10);

ctx.beginPath();
ctx.moveTo(...a);
// works correctly, but with this warning: 
// Expected 2 arguments, but got 0 or more.ts(2556)
ctx.lineTo(...b);
ctx.stroke();
ctx.closePath();
```

This code works perfectly fine according to my design. However **typescript** doesn't seem to know how many arguments are supplied and keeps warning me about it; unless I directly cast it to a tuple of 2 numbers like this:

`ctx.moveTo(...(a as unknown as [number, number]))`

**Questions:**

1. Is there a way to tell **typescript** that my Vector2 instances will be deconstructed into a fixed-length tuple when I use the spread operator?
2. Is there a way to type a generator with a fixed length?

Comment: I sincerely doubt you can do it, since even tuples themselves lose their tuple-ness when you rely on the type of their iterator like [this](https://tsplay.dev/vWkV1m).  I haven't found anything definitive yet saying this is impossible though (I kind of expected to see some GitHub issue about it but it hasn't panned out)

Comment: I opened an issue regarding this feature, if you're still interested please go ahead and leave a comment below:))) https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/42033

Comment: It is interesting but I don't know if the use case listed there would be considered compelling... how common is such a practice as opposed to just returning a tuple at once?  The generator you describe is one whose type mutates in a non-narrowing way (e.g., from something whose `next()` returns a `{done: false}` to something whose `next()` returns a `{done: true}`), and that sort of mutation is not really supported anywhere else in the type system.. meaning I'd expect this to be declined unless there's overwhelming demand for it.

Comment: I found somewhat of a workaround to trick TS into thinking my class instances are simultaneously tuples, but it only works for tuple destructuring. Maybe it can be a hint to an actual working workaround. I used it to implement a rust-like result type that can also be considered like a discrimated union of tuples.
playground link: https://t.ly/tvWp

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if a generator function is the correct abstraction here. Usually you'd use one where the length of items you're yielding is variable or unknown.

Why not work with an implementation like this:

```
class Vector2 {
  public toArray(): [number, number] {
    return [this.x, this.x];
  }
}

ctx.moveTo(...myVector.toArray());
```

This way the TypeScript compiler knows the type returned by `toArray`, and knows it will be valid when applied to `ctx.moveTo`

Comment: I actually have this toArray method implemented before i was trying the generator implementation lol. I just wanted a more concise and graceful way to do what I described above. Maybe I will write an issue about it.